# Dividing a shape in half without creating a white line down the middle

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

This seems to be a recurring problem when cutting shapes directly in half when using Illustrator's 'Divide' tool. While the shape may look ok in the program itself when I output it as a png or reduce it to a smaller size in a raster-based program like Photoshop a white line appears right down the middle. Is there a better technique to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Your image isn't aligned to the pixel grid. So that line is what photoshop/illustrator is making that is between the yellow and grey.

Answer (score 0):

@Carl Edwards you first select the shape and add the color yellow to it then duplicate it (ctrl+c > ctrl+f) and change the color of the second copy to grey then use the divide tool to cut the grey shape in half and finally delete the left part of it

Comment: This doesn't answer Carl's question.