# White artifacts when expanding extruded object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d

I use Illustrator CS6 to create a 3D pie chart. For this, I first create a "normal" pie chart and apply an extrude filter. Even though the results looks great in Illustrator, I get some white artifacts in the exported PDF (see screenshot). I tried with and without `Object > Expand appearance` and also with and without strokes. Is there a way to avoid these thin white lines? Thank you!

[image: Screenshot emphasizing white artifacts in extruded 3D pie chart]

Comment: Guessing, but they look like a line between a stroke and a fill. If you have a stroke applied prior to extrude, don't.

Comment: I get nearly the same result, with and without strokes...

Comment: @Scott hm, at least the answer of the "duplicate" does not apply. In Illustrator, everything looks good, so my monitor is capable in general. But when I do the "Expand appearance", also in Illustrator I get the white lines.

Comment: And when you expand the appearance anti-aliasing is applied. The answer in the duplicate *does* apply. More: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20611/border-on-borderless-pie-chart-illustrator-cc?lq=1 and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25823/dividing-a-shape-in-half-without-creating-a-white-line-down-the-middle?lq=1